# How to speed up row-specific operation based on values of other variables

Tags: performance, loops, stata, calculated-columns, processing-efficiency

Say I have this data:

```
sysuse auto2, clear
keep if _n<=4

describe
local N = r(N)

gen a1 = price
gen a2 = mpg
gen a3 = headroom 
gen a4 = trunk
gen a5 = weight
gen a6 = length

input yearA yearB 
1 4
1 5
2 5
1 6

keep a1-a6 yearA yearB
```

I'd like to do a row-specific operation based on the value of other variables. As an example, I'd like to add up all `a` columns corresponding to some row-specific rule, in this case starting a year after `yearA` and a year before `yearB`. So, if `yearA==1` and `yearB==5`, the starting year is `2` and the end year is `4`, so we would add `a2`, `a3`, and `a4` together to get that row's `total`. Each row has its own rule corresponding to (a function of) its values of `yearA` and `yearB`.

I came up with the following solution, which works, but it is clunky and slow:

```
gen total = .
forvalues i = 1/`N' {
    local start = yearA[`i']+1
    local end = yearB[`i']-1
    display "`start' `end'"
    *annoyingly, you can't replace with egen, so create a new variable and delete it
    egen total`i' = rowtotal(a`start'-a`end')
    replace total = total`i' if _n==`i'
    drop total`i'
}
```

As noted in the comment in the loop, I resorted to creating a new variable for each row and deleting it after using its value. Why? Because it doesn't seem like one can use `replace` with `egen`.

The actual application creates multiple variables and there are millions of observations, so it takes many hours or even days to run. What is a faster way to accomplish my goal? I am in now tied to doing things row-by-row if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gen wanted = 0 

forval j = 1/6 { 
    replace wanted = wanted + a`j' if inrange(`j', yearA + 1, yearB - 1)
}
```